# How to make multiple if statements

Tags: java, if-statement, processing

I'm using processing with java mode and I want to make more than 32 if conditions when I make it like normal way like this

```
If (-------- == --------){//dosomething}

Else If (-------- == --------){//dosomething}

Else If (-------- == --------){//dosomething}

Else If (-------- == --------){//dosomething}

Else If (-------- == --------){//dosomething}

Else {//dosomething}
```

But only the first condition works and the rest of conditions don't work 
Sometimes it gives me error " Eof "

I tried also this style

```
If (-------- == --------){//dosomething}

Else {//dosomething} 

If (-------- == --------){//dosomething}
Else {//dosomething} 


If (-------- == --------){//dosomething}
Else {//dosomething}
```

It also didn't works only the first if condition works

Note there is one time the gui didn't show the buttons or labels

How could I answer this how could I write many if conditions

this is example  the value of y1 and y comes from other device and changes one and zero when I press a hardware button this code is not complete but only the concept and also there is from y1 to y20 and from x1 to x20 only the first condition that works and I try all the rectangles with it

this is update for the question 
the full code

**in this code I use 17 pushbutton in order to read from them if it is pressed the rectangle color will be black and if it is not pressed the rectangle will be white , It works well but only for 9 inputs but the rest of the 17 didn't work ,please note that I checked all the inputs and all connections and they are working well  so how could I solve this **

```
import processing.serial.*;
import cc.arduino.*;

Arduino arduino;
int x1 = 255;
int x2 = 255;
int x3 = 255;
int x4 = 255;
int x5 = 255;
int x6 = 255;
int x7 = 255;
int x8 = 255;
int x9 = 255;
int x10 = 255;
int x11= 255;
int x12 = 255;

void setup()
{
  size(780, 600);

  //println(Arduino.list());

  arduino = new Arduino(this, Arduino.list()[0], 57600);

    arduino.pinMode(13, Arduino.INPUT);
    arduino.pinMode(12, Arduino.INPUT);
    arduino.pinMode(11, Arduino.INPUT);
    arduino.pinMode(10, Arduino.INPUT);
    arduino.pinMode(9, Arduino.INPUT);
    arduino.pinMode(8, Arduino.INPUT);
    arduino.pinMode(7, Arduino.INPUT);
    arduino.pinMode(6, Arduino.INPUT);
    arduino.pinMode(5, Arduino.INPUT);
    arduino.pinMode(4, Arduino.INPUT);
    arduino.pinMode(3, Arduino.INPUT);
    arduino.pinMode(2, Arduino.INPUT);

}


void draw()

{ 

  roundRect(10, 10, 150, 90, x1);
  roundRect(180, 10, 150, 90, x2);
  roundRect(350, 10, 150, 90, x3);
  roundRect(520, 10, 150, 90, x4);

  roundRect(10, 120, 150, 90, x5);
  roundRect(180, 120, 150, 90, x6);
  roundRect(350, 120, 150, 90, x7);
  roundRect(520, 120, 150, 90, x8);

  roundRect(10, 230, 150, 90, x9);
  roundRect(180, 230, 150, 90, x10);
  roundRect(350, 230, 150, 90, x11);
  roundRect(520, 230, 150, 90, x12);


  ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

  if (arduino.digitalRead(13) == Arduino.HIGH ) {
    x1=0;
  }                                                                                                       
  else if (arduino.digitalRead(13) == Arduino.LOW) {
    x1=255;
  }
  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

  ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

  if (arduino.digitalRead(12) == Arduino.HIGH ) {
    x2=0;
  }
  else if (arduino.digitalRead(12) == Arduino.LOW) {
    x2=255;
  }
  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

  if (arduino.digitalRead(11) == Arduino.HIGH ) {
    x3=0;
  }
  else if (arduino.digitalRead(11) == Arduino.LOW) {
    x3=255;
  }
  ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

  if (arduino.digitalRead(10) == Arduino.HIGH ) {
    x4=0;
  }                                                                                                         
  else if (arduino.digitalRead(10) == Arduino.LOW) {
    x4=255;
  }
  ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

  if (arduino.digitalRead(9) == Arduino.HIGH ) {
    x5=0;
  }
  else if (arduino.digitalRead(9) == Arduino.LOW) {
    x5=255;
  }
  //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

  if (arduino.digitalRead(8) == Arduino.HIGH ) {
    x6=0;
  }
  else if (arduino.digitalRead(8) == Arduino.LOW) {
    x6=255;
  }
  ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

  if (arduino.digitalRead(7) == Arduino.HIGH ) {
    x7=0;
  }
  else if (arduino.digitalRead(7) == Arduino.LOW) {
    x7=255;
  }
  ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

  if (arduino.digitalRead(6) == Arduino.HIGH ) {
    x8=0;
  }
  else if (arduino.digitalRead(6) == Arduino.LOW) {
    x8=255;
  }
  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

  if (arduino.digitalRead(5) == Arduino.HIGH ) {
    x9=0;
  }
  else if (arduino.digitalRead(5) == Arduino.LOW) {
    x9=255;
  }

  ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

  ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

  if (arduino.digitalRead(4) == Arduino.HIGH ) {
    x10=0;
  }
  else if (arduino.digitalRead(4) == Arduino.LOW) {
    x10=255;
  }
  ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

  if (arduino.digitalRead(3) == Arduino.HIGH ) {
    x11=0;
  }
  else if (arduino.digitalRead(3) == Arduino.LOW) {
    x11=255;
  }
  //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

  ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

  if (arduino.digitalRead(2) == Arduino.HIGH ) {
    x12=0;
  }
  else if (arduino.digitalRead(2) == Arduino.HIGH) {
    x12=255;
  }
  //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
}

void roundRect(float x, float y, float w, float h, float f) {

    float corner = w/10.0;
    float midDisp = w/20.0;

    fill(f);

    beginShape();  

    curveVertex(x+corner, y);
    curveVertex(x+w-corner, y);
    curveVertex(x+w+midDisp, y+h/2.0);

    curveVertex(x+w-corner, y+h);
    curveVertex(x+corner, y+h);
    curveVertex(x-midDisp, y+h/2.0);

    curveVertex(x+corner, y);
    curveVertex(x+w-corner, y);
    curveVertex(x+w+midDisp, y+h/2.0);

    endShape();

  }
```

[image]

Comment: Actually, it is kind of smelly code to have 50+ if/elseif ... So instead of trying to fix this, you should think of a different approach after all.

Comment: The EOF error could be caused by an accidental closing bracket.

Comment: Also Java is case-sensitive. Use `if`, `else`, and `else if`.

Comment: Are your code  compiled? `;` after if block , means you don't want `else`  block

Comment: No I don't write this semi colon

Comment: I edeit the question please take a look and if the answer is using polymorphism so how I will use it here

Answer (score 10):

When you write

```
if (-------- == --------){//dosomething};
```

This is the whole statement.  The `;` means you can't place an `else` after it.

Instead you should write

```
if (-------- == --------) {
    //dosomething
} else if (-------- == --------) {
    //dosomething else
}
```

If the first condition is the only one which is called, it means it is always true.

BTW If you have long chains of these, it is likely there is a better way to do this such as using a `switch` or polymorphism depending on what you are trying to do.

Comment: Polymorphism is a good way to reduce if chaining. You can also use State-pattern and a chaing of handlers. `handlers.stream().filter(isApplicable to state func).findFirst().get().apply()`

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: you don't do that.

Long answers: such lengthy chains of if/else are the opposite of good OO design! You don't ask objects about some state; to then make changes on some other thingy.

Instead, you should be using polymorphism.

Example:

```
abstract class Whatever {
  void doSomething();
// ... probably other methods as well
```

with and various concrete subclasses, like

```
class SpecificWhatever extends Whatever {
  @Override void doSomething() { // ...
```

And finally, you have

```
class WhateverFactory {
  Whatever createFrom(...) {
  // here you might actually need a switch or if/else
```

The essential point here is: you try hard to avoid the if/else/switch coding style. It adds a **lot** of complexity to your code and it makes it harder to maintain your code base (because it causes so much coupling within your classes).

And, just to give a more direct hint on your question; one pattern that I like is:

```
if (whatever) {
  doSomething();
  return;
}

if (somethinElse) {
  doSomethingElse();
  return;
}
```

That comes in really handy if your methods are supposed to return a value; and you can reduce the two lines to a single:

```
return doSomething();
```

Yes, that is an violation of the good old "single entry single exit" paradigm; but I think it makes if/elses chains (those that you can't avoid) much easier to read.

Given your input, I am wondering if you couldn't use one or more `Map<Integer, Integer>` objects. So, you ask the map what the X value for some Y input should be (if those numbers are really constant literals).

Comment: While I absolutely agree with the statement - and @PeterLawrey also mentions this in his answer - it kind of avoids to solve the problem of the question. I do not mean to offend - just saying. That's why I wrote it as a comment, not an answer.

Comment: My focus was on providing the "polymorphism" example. There are always people giving the "exact specific answer" that fixes the concrete problem in the question. I try to earn my reputation by providing the "second glance wider context point of view".

Comment: @Fildor OP's question is really [an XY-problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem): "I'm struggling with my solution", rather than "I'm struggling with my problem". It's entirely valid to propose a different approach if OP's approach isn't good.

Comment: @Fildor And, for the record: you inspired me to update my question and give some concrete advise on the "Y problem", too. Thanks!

Comment: @GhostCat That was my intention. :D

Comment: @AndyTurner That's right. I also think it is X-Y. It is just that I have received DVs in the past in similar situations. That's why I felt urged to leave that comment.

Comment: I'm using processing 3 with arduino with java mode I'm drowing rectangles and the color of rectangles when the values of the variables change so I put many if conditions I edited my question to show you more and please note that if I must use polymorphism how could I use it with the example that I add on the question

Comment: @GhostCat I edited the question please take a look on it again

Comment: @AndyTurner please look at it too

Answer (score 1):

The other questions are telling you to avoid putting a semicolon after an `if` statement (which you've said you didn't do) or to change your design (which doesn't really answer your question). These answers aren't **wrong**, but they also don't really address your fundamental question.

It sounds like you're just confused about the basic syntax of an `if else-if else` chain.

Here is the basic syntax:

```
if(x > 75){
   println("A");
}
else if(x > 50){
   println("B");
}
else{
   println("C");
}
```

Note that Java (and therefore Processing) is case-sensitive, so `if`, `else if` and `else` are all **lower-case**.

It's also important to make sure you count your opening and closing curly brackets. If they don't match up exactly, then you'll get the error you're talking about. Here's an example of **bad code**:

```
if(x > 75){
   println("A");
else if(x > 50){
   println("B");
}
```

You can also place unrelated `if` statements one after the other. They syntax for that just looks like this:

```
if(x > 75){
   println("A");
}
else if(x > 50){
   println("B");
}
else{
   println("C");
}

if(y < 1){
   println("D");
}
else if(y < 2){
   println("E");
}
else{
   println("F");
}
```

You can get more complicated and do things like put an `if` statement inside another `if` statement, but it doesn't sound like that's what you're trying to do here.

Comment: it works ^_^ but only for 18 and I want 34 condition so what can I do ?

Comment: @mamdouhabdelfatah I'm not sure what you're asking. This will work for any number of blocks. If it's not working, then you probably missed a parenthesis or curly bracket somewhere. Make sure your code is properly indented to make stuff like this easier to see. If you still can't get it working, post your updated code and we'll go from there.

Comment: **in this code I use 17 pushbutton in order to read from them if it is pressed the rectangle color will be black and if it is not pressed the rectangle will be white , It works well but only for 9 inputs but the rest of the 17 didn't work ,please note that I checked all the inputs and all connections and they are working well  so how could I solve this **

Comment: @mamdouhabdelfatah Please post your updated code as a [mcve] in a new question.

Comment: I can't post a question now I reach the limits

Comment: my code is not long it is redundant but with diffrent variables this is not the whole code but this is the part that have a problem that only the first 18 if statment works however all if statments I wrote them all Like each other

Comment: @mamdouhabdelfatah You're having a problem with your syntax, and we can't really help you without seeing that syntax. If you've reached the question limit, then **slow down** and take some time to put that [mcve] together.